# Read/Write to a shared vector in OpenMP slow down the program

Tags: c++, vector, openmp

I am struggling in using OpenMP for a shard vector.
In my real codes, I have a vector where store arrays, I wish using OpenMP to speed up one for loop, where I have to access all these elements inside a vector and calculate the interactions with all other elements within the cutoff range. Which means, in different chunks of the vector, the calculation of interaction is kinda independent. And the calculation is one direction and periodic, begin with the first element and end with the last element interacting with the first several elements. I just wish use two threads to test the feasibility, and I divide the workload into two parts, which I think they are independent with each other.

But the simulation time with single core is:
real    0m2.417s
user    0m2.149s
sys 0m0.011s

with multithreading is:
real    0m4.490s
user    0m8.371s
sys 0m0.024s

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the people already gave me some advices, which I really appreciate a lot. I wanna give more details of my code:
So there is a vector has 100 elements, each element would carry out calculations with the right hand neighbor nine elements. This is tricky cause actually this work can be divided into 10 pieces of kind of independent work, so I naively think this is suitable for parallel computation, but if the threads didn't running well as organized, it is very possible race condition would occur. 
So how can I specific the workload to using OpenMP, to make sure at same time, different threads are reading/writing different parts of vector?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto k = 50000;
auto cutOff = k/10;

void testFunc(vector<int> &positions){
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) schedule(static, k/2)
    for (int i = 0; i< k ; i++){
        for (int j = i; j<i+cutOff; j++){
            j=(j<=k?j:j-k);
                positions[i]+=1;
                positions[j]-=1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> pos;
    pos.resize(k);
    for (int i = 0; i<pos.size(); i++){
            pos[i]=rand() % 100;
        }

    printf("first value = %d\n", pos[0]);
    testFunc(pos);
    printf("last value = %d\n", pos[0]);
}
```

Comment: Afaik `rand()` is not thread-safe. You might actually have UB. Try replacing it with a different semi-random operation (that only uses thread-local state).

Comment: Parallelising only gains runtime if the problem to be solved actually *can* be parallelised. Would need to dig a bit deeper, but all those different indices used (`i`, `j`, `j-k`) look suspicious. If a problem cannot be parallelised well, you cannot get better than single-threaded. Even if parallelising *is* possible be aware that creating threads per se comes with some cost, too, the thread needs to be set up correctly (some space for context switches needed, some thread information initialised, a stack must be created, thread must be included in OS scheduling).

Comment: Maybe your problem is simply too small for parallel runtime compensating thread creation costs? Finally: If you happen to reside on some single-core hardware (admitted getting more and more rare these days, unless considering microcontrollers), more threads (usually) don't help out either, as only a single one can be processed at a specific point of time anyway.

Comment: General advice (unrelated to problem): You have identical duplicate code in both if/else branches. Move that out, in front of the if, and inside just leave the single code line that actually differs.

Comment: @Aconcagua Creating a thread does not take four seconds. But you are correct that this code is full of race conditions (e.g. thread 0 has `i==k/2-1` and `j==k/2`, thread 1 has `i==k/2` and `j==k/2`).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks so much, and I see your point about rand and race conditions. But if my code needs read/write from different parts of a vector, and calculating interactions of neighbors within a range(please check the update of the question), I guess it is possible for threads are always touching unrelated parts of vector, is this correct? Do you have any suggestions? I am kind of stuck for a while...

Comment: @Aconcagua Thank you for your comments! I see your point. I have to say, in my real code, this is way complicate calculations inside the loop, so it should be worthwhile for parallel. Since my code needs read/write a whole vector, and also take the interactions of neighbors elements into consideration, so I have no choice but give those wried indices. In brief, i has to interact with j(right hand neighbor elements), just in certain range, so if two treads, which means thread1 is handling first half, thread2 will take care of the second half. Ideally, two threads are touching different parts.

Comment: You might want to look into graph colorings. In short, your vector elements are graph nodes, the read dependencies of a write are edges. If you can find a valid graph coloring (no edge has the same color on both ends) then you can run the computation on all elements of the same color in parallel.

Comment: Your updated inner loop is also wrong. You modify `j`, which turns the loop endless if `i + offset >= k`.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly observed, the work can be divided into independent chunks or "sections", for example like this:

```
void testFunc(vector<int> &positions){
    int numSections = cutOff;
    for (int section = 0; section < numSections; ++section) {
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
        for (int i = section; i < k ; i += cutOff) {
            for (int offset = 0; offset < cutOff; ++offset) {
                int j = i + offset;
                if (j >= k)
                    j -= k;
                positions[i] += 1;
                positions[j] -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qdC0Rw

Note that this only works correctly if `k` is actually divisible by `cutOff`! (Consider `k = 11` and `cutOff = 10`.)

It looks like a lot of overhead to start many parallel sections if `cutOff` is large (e.g. if it is 10% of `k`), but this is more due to the algorithm itself being quadratic (it modifies `2 * k * cutOff = 0.2 * k * k` elements). So if your `k` is large, parallelization should still easily be worth it.